# Create class in ReactJs using JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create class in React using JSX. I have a dashboard built on react. I selected a part and through inspect element (Google developer console) I got the react id. Now, I want to create a class using JSX, like `class=newclass` . I have plan to use it in further CSS. I can insert manually from template. But, I want to do it through JSX, also want to test from console temporarily by running the code fron console. This is present area :-

```html
<label data-reactid=".0.b.1.0.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0">This is text</label>
```

and I want to add a class there using JSX,

```html
<label data-reactid=".0.b.1.0.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0" class="newclass">This is text</label>
```

Comment: Can you provide a little bit of clarity for me? You say you could specify the class in your template, but want to do it through JSX. But in React apps, the template is defined *using* JSX - they're not two different things. And the `reactid` is managed by the framework and appears on the resulting DOM nodes. Where are you wanting to define your class? Almost always, this is done as @madox2 describes below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<label className='newclass'>This is text</label>
```

Comment: But, how to insert the class to that particular reactid? In a page there are so many places.

Comment: Just set the `className` attribute to your JSX element

Answer (score 0):

JSX tags and attributes may differ from HTML ones.
Please view the following resource: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html

Indeed, a class in JSX is created via the "className" attribute instead of "class".
To place the class on the element you can simply do:

`<label data-reactid=".0.b.1.0.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0" className="newclass">This is text</label>`

To insert a dynamic class you should use something like the following syntax :

`var newclass = this.props.newclass;
return (
    <label data-reactid=".0.b.1.0.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0" className={newclass}>This is text</label>
);`